# SQL String correct but fetchAll empty

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am thoroughly perplexed. I am trying to execute a SQL statement in my Web app using php/PDO.  The following is my code:

```
$dbServer = DBSERVER;
$dbh = new \PDO('mysql:host=' . $myDBServer . ";port=3306", 'nameofserver', 'password', array(\PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false));
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sqlString);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

My results are ALWAYS an empty array, even when I know there should be results in my result set.  To debug, I have cut and paste my $sqlString into MySQL Workbench and that always gives me the correct result set.  So, I know that the $sqlString is legal.

The following is my $sqlString:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1 join table2 t2 ON t1.column1 = t2.column2 where t1.endDate is NULL AND t2.column3='2'
```

Comment: use a try and catch to see if it throws an exception

Comment: Why have you got slashes before PDO, like `new \PDO`?

Comment: Should I put the whole thing in the try clause or a particular statement?

Comment: Are you not using `dbname=your_db`? `$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);` as per http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php - Plus, add `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened, since you're not checking for errors, which you should.

Comment: @Fred-ii-Brilliant! Worked perfectly with those changes. Many thanks!

Comment: If you want the question to be properly closed, I can put in an answer just so it doesn't remain in the unanswered category. Or, you can simply delete the question. Either way, it's your call. I'm just glad it got resolved.

Comment: Yes, please put in an answer and I will mark as correct.

Comment: @worldofjr You need to use a backslash if you're working within your own namespace (or `use PDO` somewhere).

Comment: @whistler It has been done, *cheers*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to select a DB, i.e.: `dbname=your_db` which isn't present in your connection code.

For example:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
```

As per the manual:

- **http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php**

Plus, add:

```
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

right after the connection is opened, since it will check for errors, a vital tool when coding.

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.